# How do I put multiple statements under one if condition

Tags: python

Currently part of my code looks like this:

```
answer = input('Would you like to continue [y]es or [n]o?')
if answer == 'y': statement
if answer == 'y': statement
if answer == 'y': statement
if answer == 'y': statement
if answer == 'y': statement
```

Is there any way for me to bypass having to write that beginning part over and over and just group multiple statements under one if condition?

Comment: Press `Enter` after colon (`:`) and indent your `statement`s by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
answer = input(‘Would you like to continue [y]es or [n]o?’)
if answer == ‘y’:
    for _ in range(5):
        statement
```

Answer (score 0):

[Python uses indentation for grouping of statements](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html?highlight=indentation#why-does-python-use-indentation-for-grouping-of-statements).

So if you try the code below:

```py
answer = input('Would you like to continue [y]es or [n]o?')
if answer == 'y':
    print('statement1')
    print('statement2')
    print('statement3')
    print('statement4')
    print('statement5')
print('finished')
```

it prints the followings.

---

If you enter 'y':

```
Would you like to continue [y]es or [n]o?y
statement1
statement2
statement3
statement4
statement5
finished
```

---

If you enter 'n':

```
Would you like to continue [y]es or [n]o?n
finished
```